# Duplicate in same row in different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

i have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #my_table (
  intID int IDENTITY (1, 1),
  num_1 varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  num_2 varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  num_3 varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  num_4 varchar(100),
  num_5 varchar(100),
  isDuplicate char(1) DEFAULT 'N'
)

INSERT INTO #my_table (num_1, num_2, num_3, num_4, num_5)
  VALUES ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
INSERT INTO #my_table (num_1, num_2, num_3, num_4, num_5)
  VALUES ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
INSERT INTO #my_table (num_1, num_2, num_3, num_4, num_5)
  VALUES ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
INSERT INTO #my_table (num_1, num_2, num_3, num_4, num_5)
  VALUES ('a', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'e')
INSERT INTO #my_table (num_1, num_2, num_3, num_4, num_5)
  VALUES ('a', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'e')
INSERT INTO #my_table (num_1, num_2, num_3, num_4, num_5)
  VALUES ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'c')
```

I need to find duplicates in columns and get the row number which is duplicate.

my result should be 
duplicate rows last 3 rows and is duplicate flag should be updated to 'Y'

Comment: What code did you try?

Comment: select *
from
 (
  select num_1, num_2, num_3, num_4, num_5
     ,row_number() 
      over (partition by num_1, num_2, num_3, num_4, num_5
            order by intid desc) as rn 
  from #my_table
 ) as dt
where rn > 1  : but this updates the row 2 & 3 which should not

Comment: Please show the results that you want.  You have specified two different things (finding the duplicates, setting a flag to `'Y'`).

Comment: Please delete your comment and add it to your question by clicking the "edit" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could also do the trick:

```
UPDATE #my_table
    SET isDuplicate = 'Y'
WHERE intID IN (
    SELECT intID FROM #my_table
    WHERE EXISTS 
       (SELECT 1 
        FROM (VALUES 
                   (num_1)
                  ,(num_2)
                  ,(num_3)
                  ,(num_4)
                  ,(num_5)) AS X (n)
        WHERE NULLIF(n, '') IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY n
    HAVING COUNT(*)>1
   )
)
```

More information about **table value constructors** you can find [here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/sql-training/table-value-constructors-in-sql-server-2008/).

Comment: Good Job.. Looks perfect.+

Comment: Thanks a ton Valerica

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick :

```
select  num_1, num_2, num_3, count(*)
from #my_table
group by num_1, num_2, num_3
having count(*) > 1
```

Regards

Comment: This would set the last column to "Y"?

Answer (score 0):

This would set the duplicate column in the table to 'Y' if its a duplicate, you can the query from that

```
UPDATE #my_table
SET isDuplicate = 'Y'
WHERE intID IN
(
    SELECT intID
    FROM
    (
        SELECT intID, num_1, num_2, num_3,num_4, num_5,
               RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY num_1, num_2, num_3, num_4, num_5 ORDER BY intID ASC) AS [rank]
        FROM #my_table
    ) a
    WHERE [rank] > 1
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE #my_table
SET isDuplicate = 
CASE
    WHEN
    (select count(*) 
    from #my_table t2
    where t2.intID <> #my_table.intID
    and t2.num_1 = #my_table.num_1
    and t2.num_2 = #my_table.num_2
    and t2.num_3 = #my_table.num_3
    and t2.num_4 = #my_table.num_4
    and t2.num_5 = #my_table.num_5
 ) > 0 then 'Y'
 ELSE 'N'
 END
```