# How to select the first of duplicate rows in MySQL (but where duplicate data is in different columns)

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, subquery

This is a variation of the 'find first of duplicated rows' problem, but one where the rows are obviously duplicates to a human using their common sense but are not duplicate rows as defined by MySQL.

I have the table below representing payments due from members of an organisation.
Each row holds member data and, if their partner is also a joint member, the same data for their joint, otherwise those columns are null or an empty string. 
The table is currently ordered by member_name, member_ID.

**All** the members appear in the member columns, so if a member / joint tuple appears in one row it will eventually appear 'duplicated' somewhere else, but with the member and joint fields reversed.

Exactly where this appears depends upon the alphabetical order of the joint's name.

The table originates from elsewhere for another purpose so I have no control over its structure when I get it. eg

TABLE payment_due :

```
member_id | member_name | member_payment | joint_id | joint_name | joint_payment
==========|=============|================|==========|============|=============
    11    | ARNOLD      |      40        | (NULL)   |            |   (NULL)
    22    | BAKER       |      36        |   88     |   ELNET    |     35
    33    | COOPER      |      30        |   44     |   COOPER   |     30
    44    | COOPER      |      30        |   33     |   COOPER   |     30
    55    | DAVIS       |      40        | (NULL)   |            |   (NULL)
    88    | ELNET       |      35        |   22     |   BAKER    |     36
    66    | FRENCH      |      37        |   99     |   JOYCE    |     50
    77    | GRANT       |      45        | (NULL)   |            |   (NULL)
    99    | JOYCE       |      50        |   66     |   FRENCH   |     37 
   100    | LAWSON      |      46        | (NULL)   |            |   (NULL)
```

Please can someone help me to devise a query that will show all rows containing non joint members plus just the first row of a joint relationship i.e. not showing the duplicate/reversed row.

(I define 'first' as being earlier in the sequence when the original table has ORDER BY member_name, member_ID applied).

Ideally I'd like two queries, one returning the first of the two reversed pairs and one returning the last, so that reports can be generated in alphabetical order of member name whether we consider the 'name' to be that of the member or of their joint (see below).

**Desired results**

Query 1 result (using the first joint occurrence)

TABLE payment_due

```
member_id | member_name | member_payment | joint_id | joint_name | joint_payment
==========|=============|================|==========|============|=============
    11    | ARNOLD      |      40        | (NULL)   |            |   (NULL)
    22    | BAKER       |      36        |   88     |   ELNET    |     35
    33    | COOPER      |      30        |   44     |   COOPER   |     30
    55    | DAVIS       |      40        | (NULL)   |            |   (NULL)
    66    | FRENCH      |      37        |   100    |   JOYCE    |     50
    77    | GRANT       |      45        | (NULL)   |            |   (NULL)
   100    | LAWSON      |      46        | (NULL)   |            |   (NULL)

(ie member_id's 44, 88, 100 not shown)
```

or Query 2 result (using the last joint occurrence)

TABLE payment_due

```
member_id | member_name | member_payment | joint_id | joint_name | joint_payment
==========|=============|================|==========|============|=============
    11    | ARNOLD      |      40        | (NULL)   |            |   (NULL)
    44    | COOPER      |      30        |   33     |   COOPER   |     30
    55    | DAVIS       |      40        | (NULL)   |            |   (NULL)
    88    | ELNET       |      35        |   22     |   BAKER    |     36
    77    | GRANT       |      45        | (NULL)   |            |   (NULL)
    99    | JOYCE       |      50        |   66     |  FRENCH    |     37 
   100    | LAWSON      |      46        | (NULL)   |            |   (NULL)

(ie member_id's 22, 33, 66 not shown)
```

**What I've tried**

I've played with adding an incremented column and doing a union of non joints and the usual 'first of duplicate row' SQL structure but I cannot see how to define my reversed rows as being 'duplicates' when the data being duplicated appears in different columns (code so far below).

There is a db-fiddle here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/f7DoySyi8boDG3DxMpcD86/0
(I used DB-Fiddle as SQLfiddle seems to having problems at the moment, at least for me)

**Code tried**

```
-- make a temp table with an extra column holding a unique identifier 'orderby'
SET @x:=0;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE payment_due_2 AS
   (SELECT 
    @x:=@x+1 AS orderby,
    payment_due.*
    FROM payment_due);  

-- make a copy of the temp table to avoid problems with reopening temp tables
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE payment_due_3 AS
(SELECT * FROM payment_due_2);

 -- make a second copy of the temp table for the same reason
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE payment_due_4 AS
(SELECT * FROM payment_due_2);

SELECT * FROM 
  (
   SELECT payment_due_4.*  -- get all the non joints
   FROM payment_due_4 
   WHERE joint_id IS NULL

   UNION 

   SELECT payment_due_2.*    -- get the first of the 'duplicates'
    FROM payment_due_2 
    JOIN
      (SELECT MIN(orderby) AS min_id
       FROM payment_due_3 
       GROUP BY payment_due_3.member_id  
       ) AS T3
    ON payment_due_2.orderby = T3.min_id
    ) as T5
 ORDER BY member_name, member_id;
```

I looked at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47200878/duplicate-in-same-row-in-different-columns) that appeared to be a duplicate of mine but I didn't find it very clear. This was because,as another SO user said, "it specified two different things (finding the duplicates, setting a flag to 'Y')" and the accepted answer did not address duplicate data being in two different columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that you should be able to filter out unwanted duplicates using a correlated subquery with an EXISTS condition.

This query retains the duplicate with the smallest member_id (and records without a joint_id as well) :

```
SELECT *
FROM payment_due p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM payment_due p1
    WHERE 
        p1.member_id = p.joint_id
        AND p1.joint_id = p.member_id
        AND p1.member_id < p.member_id
)
```

To get the duplicate with the highest member_id, just change the last condition in the subquery :

```
AND p1.member_id > p.member_id
```

Comment: Thank you. that did it. I see now that the trick is that rather than coding to identify one of the duplicate rows as such, you first get both of them with 'WHERE p1.member_id = p.joint_id AND p1.joint_id = p.member_id' and then eliminate one with the  'AND p1.member_id > p.member_id'. Brilliant idea and obvious now that you've pointed it out.  Very glad to see that SO still has some members such as yourself simply willing to help others. (I do get rather fed up with those that just criticize, edit or delete questions)

Comment: Welcome @user2834566 ! In my opinion your question was well documentent and met the SO standards ! You got the logic right, and now you see that it’s not that different from what is suggested in the other question that you linked (only the conditions in the subquery change).